# Simple Poco TCP networking application core dumping

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm playing around with `Poco` at the moment and trying to build a simple `TCP` server-client application.
The `Client`'s only task in this example is to echo all received data back to the sender.
If I execute the compiled application I get the following message when quitting:

```
*** Error in `./gameserver': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffd4896cbf8 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't really understand the problem here. I think it has something to do with the `Poco` part of the code and me missing something important when using the `Poco` stuff.

Would be nice if someone could tell me what's wrong with my code.

Code:

```
class Client : public TCPServerConnection
{
public:
    explicit Client(const StreamSocket &socket)
        : TCPServerConnection(socket)
    {
    }

    ~Client()
    {
        socket().close();
    }

    void run()
    {
        char buffer[256];
        int n = socket().receiveBytes(buffer, 256);
        while(n > 0)
        {
            socket().sendBytes(buffer, n);
            n = socket().receiveBytes(buffer, 256);
        }
    }
};

class Factory : public TCPServerConnectionFactory
{
public:
    TCPServerConnection* createConnection(const StreamSocket &socket)
    {
        return new Client(socket);
    }
};

class Server
{
public:
    explicit Server(const string &endpoint)
        : address(endpoint), socket(address), factory(), server(&factory, socket)
    {
        server.start();
    }

    ~Server()
    {
        server.stop();
    }

private:
    SocketAddress address;
    ServerSocket socket;
    TCPServer server;
    Factory factory;
};

int main()
{
    {
        Server server("localhost:5556");
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a double free of the `Factory`. Both the `Server` and the `TCPServer` objects own the `Factory`, so they both free it when they're done with it.

The fix is to pick one and let it, and only it, own the factory. Here's one way:

```
class Server
{
public:
    explicit Server(const string &endpoint)
        : address(endpoint), socket(address), server(new Factory(), socket)
    {
        server.start();
    }

    ~Server()
    {
        server.stop();
    }

private:
    SocketAddress address;
    ServerSocket socket;
    TCPServer server;
};
```

Comment: thanks it's working now! I would like to know how you found the cause for this? Did you simply knew it beforehand because you knew the source or have you used any tools? I often have difficulties with debugging my C++ applications because most of the time the error messages don't mean anything useful to me. It gets even worse if the error is e.g. a segmentation fault without any detailed error message at all.

Comment: @TorbenJonas There are a lot of different ways you could debug this kind of problem. Analyzing the point at which the failure occurred (post-mortem debugging of the core file) is one way. Personally, I wouldn't use a C++ library that implemented transfer of ownership through passing naked pointers unless I had no choice. In this particular case, I figured it out by code inspection -- I saw code that passed a naked pointer to an object it owned into a library function and knew that was the likely culprit. (If you were supposed to do that, the function would likely take a reference.)